# iot-edge raspberry-noobs- nodejs sample - interact with azureiot

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-iot-edge

[error image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4621765/35331037-ca94bd14-00fd-11e8-87fa-2738b512a30d.jpg)I am getting error with
https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/tree/master/v1/samples/nodejs_simple_sample

A) ./build_nodejs.sh [RAN SUCCESSFUL AND TOOK HOURS]
As per instruction I have now got NODE_INCLUDE and NODE_LIB environment variables
Which is the correct place to set these?

B) WHEN I RUN ./build.sh --enable-nodejs-binding

error says about setting the node_include and node_lib files

I am using RASPBERRY PI with NOOBS and want to interact with azureiothub as shown in the sample.
I was able to successfully run the other sample which writes to log file

Comment: When you executed `./build_nodejs.sh` successfully, have you noted the message about setting the NODE_INCLUDE and NODE_LIB environment variables at the end?You need to copy and paste the message to set the environment variables.@rahul mehta

Comment: yes i did that, but i still get error as per image attached

Comment: Please try to use `printenv` command to check whether the environment variables have been set.If not,try to set again.

Comment: yes i can see those 2 variable on running command printenv Below is the complete error i am getting now after setting variable.
As per steps I ran ./build.sh --enable-nodejs-binding in tools folder and got attached error 
I added 3 images but its single information/error in 3 images...  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4621765/35494949-3505ab74-04e4-11e8-8785-e41eb2ffd83d.jpg  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4621765/35494951-37129896-04e4-11e8-97dd-c96a8bb0af80.jpg  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4621765/35494952-38f43f66-04e4-11e8-90a1-a1dbe201226d.jpg

Comment: find cmakerror.log attached https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4621765/35495276-24c84008-04e6-11e8-97e4-70d83dd86f35.jpg

Comment: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4621765/35495498-2d7acd78-04e7-11e8-8c13-e9380c52cc0c.jpg and  https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4621765/35495500-2e59052a-04e7-11e8-8df7-74207dd93eb6.jpg  shows two variables are set

Comment: What is the system running on your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: yes on raspberry pi, i even tried alternate command as https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/issues/491, i am just getting variable error though i can see the variable with the command printenv

Comment: Im trying to test this issue on my Raspberry Pi3 with Ubuntu Mate, if there is any progress, I will let you know.

Comment: Thanks Michael Xu, in time being I am trying rm -r v1/build_libuv
v1/tools/build.sh --enable-nodejs-binding --disable-native-remote-modules --disable-ble-module --rebuild-deps  [disabling the blu thooth module] as suggested on github forum

Comment: I have tested this issue on raspberry with NOOBS. It works. Have you set up your development environment for Azure IoT Edge? This [document](https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/blob/master/v1/doc/devbox_setup.md#set-up-a-linux-development-environment) describes how to prepare your development environment to use Azure IoT Edge, it is similar like on Ubuntu. @rahul mehta

Comment: I am trying again and will let u know. following this  This document https://github.com/Azure/iot-edge/blob/master/v1/doc/devbox_setup.md#set-up-a-linux-development-environment

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `cmake -E environment` to see if the environment variable is being passed to cmake.